# redux toolkit states are loosing when i access throught the URL manually in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-toolkit

i would like to implement protected routes  in my react application
but after i have implemented its working well with component changing

issue when i access the components and router tree through manually then my redux toolkit states are getting initialize(loosing states as when app refresh)

i have authenticated jwt token method from my node server
when i login protected route HOC component will be checking redux toolkit state token

its working as i expected when i login the user and im storing the userId and accessToken in the store and protected route is throughing the user to the dashboard

here is the real problem
i want to access this url manually after the user is authenticated
`dashboard/:item` ---> anything random like this `dashboard/${product_name}`
when i hit this in the URL search on browser, store is getting refreshing

im not sure whether this problem is in router or redux-toolkit implementation

everytime if access through the url method im redirecting to the login page
because toolkit states have been overridden

i'm providing reference code here

**authGuard.js**

```
function AuthGuard({ children }) {
const values = useSelector(state => state.authReducer)

    if(!values.userId) {
        console.log(values.userId)
        return  <Navigate to="/signin" />
    } 
    return <>{children}</>
  }
  
  export default AuthGuard;
```

and here is my authSlice

**authSlice.js**

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
    name : "auth",
    initialState :{
        token : null,
        signupError : "",
        loginError : "",
        loading : false,
        loginLoading : false,
        userId : undefined
    },
    reducers : {
        registerToken : (state , {payload})=>{
            state.token = payload.accessToken
            state.userId = payload.id
        },
        loginToken : (state , {payload})=>{
            state.token = payload.accessToken
            state.userId = payload.id
            console.log(current(state))
        },
        setLoading : (state , {payload})=> {state.loading = payload},
        setRegisterError : (state , {payload})=> {state.signupError = payload},
        setLoginError : (state , {payload}) => {state.loginError = payload},
        setLoginLoading : (state ,{payload}) => {state.loginLoading = payload},
        setToken : (state , {payload}) => {state.token = payload 
        console.log(current(state))
        },
        logoutToken : (state)=>{
            state.token = null
            state.userId = null
        }
    }
})
```

here is my react-router array

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <AuthLayout/>,
    children: [
      {
        path: "signin",
        element: <Login/>
      },

      {
        path : "signup",
        element : <Register/>
      } 
    ],
  },
  {
    path : "/dashboard",
    element : <AuthGuard>
                <MainLayout/>
              </AuthGuard>,
    children : [
      {
        path : "",
        element : <DashBoard/>
      },
      {
        path : ":item",
        element : <SearchProductsContainer/>,
      },
      {
        path : ":item/:product",
        element : <ProductBriftDetailsContainer/>
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

i want to allow the user after authenticated to this routes even thought they type throught the url manually
and one more thing
if the user is directly accesing the login page without logout i need to through that user directly to the page where visited last time

Comment: Redux is in-memory state management, when the page is reloaded the state is wiped. You will need to persist the state to some longer-term storage, i.e. localStorage. This isn't an issue with `react-router` or `redux-toolkit`.

Comment: Previously i have used redux-toolkit i was not happed when i integrate authentication with keycloak and even with firebase

Comment: Previously where you persisting the state somewhere? Using `redux-persist`?